# IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 0

Tags: java, arraylist

I am getting an exception in my Java program regarding my array list of array lists. I've included the relevant part of my program below.

```
List<List<Integer>> inverse_men_preference = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        inverse_men_preference.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(n));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            inverse_men_preference.get(i).add(marriage.getMenPreference().get(i).get(j), j);
        }
    }
```

I looked at similar questions, but I still could not figure out why my array list's size is considered empty. I am new to Java, so I figured I had some fundamental misunderstanding preventing me from understanding the error. Any input or suggestions would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 4):

You've put no items in the ArrayList. the `n` is simply its capacity, not its size. Always use a collection's `size()` and avoid using [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) as you're doing here.

Comment: Thanks. Why wouldn't the first for loop in which I add ten array lists in the array list not make the size ten? I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: @Gopika He is obviously talking about the ArrayList you've added to `inverse_men_preference`. They are empty.

Comment: @Tom Thank you for the clarification! I guess I automatically assumed the problem was with the ArrayList inverse_men_preference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error you are getting is because of `marriage.getMenPreference().get(i).get(j)` part. Maybe either of the lists returned by `marriage.getMenPreference()` does not have `ith` or `jth` element. If we replace that with constant, it works fine, e.g.:

```
int n = 2;
List<List<Integer>> inverse_men_preference = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    inverse_men_preference.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(n));
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        inverse_men_preference.get(i).add(0, j);
    }
}
```

Make sure you have `marriage.getMenPreference()` initialised/populated before the above gets executed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is not the issue as these are passed into the function already populated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the problem with any of your lists. The exception is appointing while instead of adding an single integer - you call method "add" with two arguments. This works good:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 10;
    List<List<Integer>> inverse_men_preference = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        inverse_men_preference.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(n));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            inverse_men_preference.get(i).add(5);
}
```

whereas this is what you do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 10;
    List<List<Integer>> inverse_men_preference = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        inverse_men_preference.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(n));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            inverse_men_preference.get(i).add(5, 34);
}
```

List is such a collection you can insert elements to the beginning / in the middle / to the end of it. While it is empty you cannot add element e.g. on the fifth position. What I would recommend is using arrays instead of arraylist, hence you will be able to insert values in different positions of it at any time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is an add method that takes two arguments--the index and the element to be added to that index. So why wouldn't my approach work?

Comment: @Gopika I have edited my answer to explain your exception.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I used an array list of arrays like you recommended. This got rid of my initial error since I don't have the empty array list problem. However, it still causes an error later because I get a null pointer exception since the arrays in the arraylist have not been initialized. Which is essentially the same as my earlier problem. Also, I realized I need to use an array list rather than an array anyway because I want to make use of the shifting property of the add method when two objects map to the same index.

Comment: @Gopika try this: http://pastebin.com/3inVAxDB and tell if it worked. It would be really cool if you would accept my answer as the correct one, cheers!